# Creating CRUD with pymongo in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to build a CRUD view with MongoDB using PyMongo (and I'm a little bit new to mongo/pymongo).

I created the full CRUD view using the normal forms and mysql, how can I use Mongo to do the same?

these are the main parts for my contacts app so far:

models.py:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
```

forms.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

and views.py:

```
def contact_list(request):
    contacts = Contact.objects.all().order_by("phone_number")
    return render(request, 'contacts/contact_list.html', {'contacts': contacts})

def save_contact_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            contacts = Contact.objects.all().order_by("phone_number")
            data['html_contact_list'] = render_to_string('contacts/includes/partial_contact_list.html', {
            'contacts': contacts
        })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def contact_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return save_contact_form(request, form, 'contacts/includes/partial_contact_create.html')

def contact_update(request, pk):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=contact)
    else:
        form = ContactForm(instance=contact)
    return save_contact_form(request, form, 'contacts/includes/partial_contact_update.html')

def contact_delete(request, pk):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        contacts = Contact.objects.all()
        data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('contacts/includes/partial_contact_list.html', {
        'contacts': contacts
    })
    else:
        context = {'contact': contact}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('contacts/includes/partial_contact_delete.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I also have a mongo.py to set a simple connection.

I would appreciate the help!
I've looked at the docs of pymongo, and mongodb, and django but I couldn't find anything that matches what I'm looking for.

Thanks, and sorry for the long post!

<------EDIT 1 : PyMongo File ---->

mongo.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from pymongo import MongoClient

class MongoConn(object):
    clients = {}

    @classmethod
    def client(cls, name='default'):
        if name not in cls.clients:
            if name not in settings.MONGODB:
                return None
            cls.clients[name] = cls(settings.MONGODB.get(name))
        return cls.clients.get(name)

    def __init__(self, db_config):
        self.conn = MongoClient(host=db_config.get('HOST'), port=db_config.get('PORT'))
        self.db_name = db_config.get('NAME')
        self._db = None

    @property
    def db(self):
        if not self._db:
            self._db = self.get_db()
        return self._db

    def get_db_name(self):
        """
        :rtype: string
        """
        return self.db_name

    def get_db(self, db_name=None):
        """
        :param db_name:
        :rtype: pymongo.database.Database
        """
        return self.conn[db_name or self.get_db_name()]

    def get_collection(self, collection_name):
        """
        :param string collection_name:
        :rtype: pymongo.collection.Collection
        """
        return self.db[collection_name]
```

Comment: I would recommend you start writing some pymongo code in a class and using that class to do all the logic in your views. I can't really do much for you until you start showing what you've done with pymongo thus far.

Comment: I've already start to build that kind of class, I've just edited the main post with the code.

Comment: http://mongoengine.org/

Comment: I don't get how to create a connection to Mongo instead of MySQL by default in django, how can I create the tables directly from django like I do with MySQL, and what the basics commands I have so I can read, write, update and delete contact information